# Unable to pass multiple POST parameters from Django template

Tags: python, django, http, post, django-templates

I'm passing POST parameters via a Django template. The template is basic:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'registration_id' %}"> 
{% csrf_token %} 
<input name="registration_id" value="{{ registration_id }}"> 
<input name="device_id" value="{{ device_id }}"> 
<button>Submit</button> 
</form>
```

In the [model](https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications/blob/master/push_notifications/models.py#L41), `registration_id` is a required `TextField`, whereas `device_id` is an optional hex field. To test my set up, I use a Mozilla add-on called [HttpRequester](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httprequester/). It works perfectly if:

1- I POST content to my URL like so:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=foobar&registration_id=foo
```

2- or like so:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=foobar&registration_id=foo&device_id=
```

(i.e. pass nothing in `device_id`, but mention the variable)

3- But nothing gets POSTed if I do:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=foobar&registration_id=foo&device_id=1234abcd
```

(ensuring device_id is a hex value)

Views.py is:

```
class DeviceCreateView(FormView):
    model = GCMDevice
    form_class = DeviceForm
    template_name = "deviceobj_form.html"
    def form_valid(self, form): 
        reg_id = self.request.POST.get('registration_id','')
        dev_id = self.request.POST.get('device_id','')
        if is_hex(dev_id):
            GCMDevice.objects.create(registration_id=reg_id, device_id=dev_id)
        else:
            GCMDevice.objects.create(registration_id=reg_id, device_id='abcdef2222')
        return render_to_response('success.html',RequestContext(self.request,{}))

def is_hex(s):
    try:
        int(s,16)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

**What am I doing wrong in 3rd choice?**

Comment: "doesn't even make it out of the template" doesn't make sense. You're not using the template here to make the POST, you're using an external tool that sends the HTTP request separately. I guess that what's happening is that your form is invalid for some reason, so the template is being redisplayed; you will definitely need to post the view.

Comment: remove the external tool from your testing and test it directly (with a template form) with `debug=True` to see where your code is failing.

Comment: Include your views.py

Comment: Included views.py. Debug is set to TRUE btw, I don't see an error, the template just reloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an error in the push-notifications [library](https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications) I was using, not in my code posted above. With either postgres or mysql as the database engine, attempting to create or update a gcm device using a form and http post was failing. The validators were being run against a string value, thus min and max validation were failing. Rewrote the validators to run against an integer value.